# Performance problems with xboxdrv

Tags: driver, emulation, input-device, joystick, gamepad

I wanna use the RPi as an emulation machine, thanks to **RetroPie** this is not a big problem. To control everything I want to connect multiple **Xbox 360 wireless** gamepads. This is possible by using **xboxdrv**.

It's easy to establish a connection via `sudo xboxdrv -s -wid x`. The problem now is the performance. The system is receiving any pushed buttons very slowly and sometimes won't recognize if the button is still pressed.

It gets worse if I try to connect more than 1 controller. The emulator seems also to be slowed down.

I've overclocked the RPi to 1000MHz for testing purposes, but that did not change anything.

I guess that it must work with at least 1 gamepad anyhow, since there are different articles online showing how to connect such a controller (all of them do not really help with my problem unfortunately)

*NOTE: I'm not allowed to create tags yet, so I needed to take existing ones which do not fit very well. Would be nice if someone with editing access could alter them to make more sense. I would suggest the following: `retropie gaming gamepad xbox360 emulation` *

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute xboxdrv directly from a interactive shell.

Some users experience dropped events if they start xboxdrv from rc.local or another script.
But if you start xboxdrv from a shell, it seems to work well.

Now, the big problem is the reason for that to happen.

Comment: I usually start the driver via ssh shell from another computer. That way I can run RetroPie on my TV and control driver-related things via my PC. Does that qualify as an interactive shell?

Comment: Yes :) Last night I played Super Mario for a couple of hours without any problems.
I booted my Pi, waited for Emulationstation to start, exited it, executed:
xboxdrv --trigger-as-button --wid 0 --led 2 --deadzone 4000 --silent &
sleep 1

Comment: Rewriting my comment, I couldn't edit the previous one:
Yes :) Last night I played Super Mario for a couple of hours without any problems.
1.I booted my Pi
2.waited for Emulationstation to start
3.exited it
4.executed:
xboxdrv --trigger-as-button --wid 0 --led 2 --deadzone 4000 --silent &
sleep 1
5.and then started emulationstation again

Comment: Just followed your steps and it's still laggy :/ After searching a lot and reading through various pages I'm starting to think that something is wrong with my USB-ports...

Comment: MonsDaR, maybe the problem is because it is overclocked. I reinstalled the OS to start from scratch, and it seems to be working now. It wasn't working well when my raspberry pi was overclocked.

Comment: I also have noticed that it is way better (still laggy) if I remove other USB devices (I had a wireless keyboard receiver plugged in, probably uses Bluetooth internal, like the Xbox receiver).